# Handling Print popup with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, printing, popupwindow

I'm working on a test automation project. I need to click on the Print button (there's a functional aim behind this print) so that when I click on the button a print popup is displayed. I want to click on the Cancel button on this popup or simply close it.
I'm working with selenium C# and the browser is Firefox (default browser)
I tried this method :

```
public void ClosePrintPopup()
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)m_WebDriver;
            jse.ExecuteScript("setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 0);");
            m_WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(m_WebDriver.WindowHandles.Last());
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            string JSPath = "document.querySelector('body>print-preview-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('#sidebar').shadowRoot.querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-button.cancel-button')";
            IWebElement cancelBtn = (IWebElement)jse.ExecuteScript($"return {JSPath}");
            cancelBtn.Click();
        }
```

and I have this exception

```
  Message: 
    --- Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
    --- Method: SP_AutomateRenew::TC_Subscription2 ------------
    
    --- Message: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
    --- Source: WebDriver
```

Comment: The error message is clear. The given element `body>print-preview-app` is null. Be sure that there is an element like that.